# How to change different Magento backend language for sub-admins?

Tags: magento-1.9, language, administration, acl

We got multi-lingual team, and couple of members do not speak each others languages. Is it possible to set Magento backend in separate languages for corresponding users?

Looking for same like below link but didnt find solution: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7088830/949003

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a cool module which enables your user to set the language preferences.

Whenever the admin is loggingin, It will change the locale respective to the customer.

https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_BackendDefaultLanguage Cheers. Give a try

PS: I am running 3 stores with this module.

Comment: Yes. I am already checking it. Lets see if it works. Thanks

Comment: @Sunder  How to use this. I installed it but nothing happened in admin. Can you please guide me how you are using it.

FYI: I have created few sub-admin user and and assigned role to them well.

Comment: start following this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/34194/29175

Comment: Dont worry about modman and stuff.. Its just a tool for integration. Just copy and paste according to the directory structure. 
and then you can find settings in system->my account.